# prosac algorithm implementation detail, meaning and importance

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, ransac

I understand that Prosac algorithm is a modified version of Ransac algorithm that it samples according to the quality of data points. However, I cannot understand the details of the algorithm implementation. Specifically, I cannot understand the two "ifs" in both step 1 and step 2. Why do they mean in the algorithm and what are their importance?

[image: algorithm]

Reference:

Matching with PROSAC – Progressive Sample Consensus http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~matas/papers/chum-prosac-cvpr05.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by defining the variables at play here.

## Variables

**N**: Total number of samples.

**m**: Complexity of the geometric model.

**t**: Number of iterations of the loop.

**n***: Termination length (number of samples to consider before stopping).

**TN**: Parameter that defines after how many samples PROSAC becomes equivalent to RANSAC.

**Tn**: Average number of samples from the **n** top-ranked points.

**Tn'**: Ceiled value of **Tn**

## Part one

The first *if* checks if you have exhausted the possible samples (meaning that you have sampled **Tn'** samples). So, to avoid sampling again a sample already sampled, you increase the number of considered points. You can increase the number if **n < n***, meaning that you can't consider more than **n*** points, your stopping criteria.

## Part two

For the second if, we have to look at the behavior of **Tn'** with respect to **t**. We know that when **t = Tn'**, we add one point in our considered points set. So, **Tn'** will always be bigger than **t**, except when we can't sample more points, aka when **n = n*** (the first if).

When we consider the **n*** top-ranked points, **Tn'** will stop growing and **t** will eventually become bigger or equal to **Tn'**.

So, as long as **t** does not exceed **Tn'**, we will sample the PROSAC way (point **n** and **m-1** points from the top **n-1**.

When we have sampled at least **Tn'** times, we do just like RANSAC, sample **m** points from all from the **n*** top-ranked points.